# how to display webp format(.webp) images in all browser?

Tags: php, image

We have converted the images to webp format. it supports only in chrome brower for display. how to display in all browser ? 
Also have to display in android , IOS?

Comment: Why don't you use a supported format instead (jpeg, png, svg), until webp becomes mature enough?

Comment: if we convert the images in webp format. it reduce the image size and also images in same quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a polyfill technology like [WebPJS](http://webpjs.appspot.com/). However, due to the additional javascript and browser side conversion, overall performance and bandwidth savings may be less or negative.

Comment: its not support in IE latest Version.

Comment: Although it's not supported, for the majority of pictures it works in later IEs as well. However, this Polyfill development seems to be dead anyway, as the last update was in November 2013.

Comment: thanks. any other library is available? i think this only one.